# Using the conditions value in if/else

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it's possible to access a condition's value directly like the following example.

```
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"]
if(a.indexOf("orange") !== -1){
  console.log(this) //as a.indexOf("orange") has been evaluated already above this prints 2
}
```

This would also make ternary operators less bloaty

```
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"]
var b = ((a.indexOf("orange") !== -1) ? this : '') //"this" equals 2
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Clearing this question up for any future visitors.
Basically this question is about retrieving the resulting value of what is evaluated in an if/else statement. In the example of

```
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"]
if(a.indexOf("orange") !== -1){ //is basically if(2 !== -1)
  console.log(this) //would then be "2" from the already evaluted a.indexOf from above
}
```

Comment: Note that what you're asking for is *not* accessing the condition's value. The condition is either `true` or `false`. You want to access the value of one of the sub-expressions within the condition (specifically, what `indexOf()` returns).

Comment: @Barmar Hence why the question seems to have confused everyone. It would have made sense to ask about the conditions value, which could work in theory

Comment: Which is why one should read all the details in the question, including the comments in the code, to make sense of it. People aren't always very good at finding the right words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply store it before the statement if the goal is to not evaluate twice. The answer to your literal question is no.

```
const orangeIndex = a.indexOf("orange")

if (orangeIndex !== -1) {
  console.log(orangeIndex)
}
```

Same concept applies to the ternary operator.

As others have shown, you can also declare a variable and do the actual assignment in the if statement itself, but IMO this makes your code less readable without adding any value.

Comment: Accepted for answering my literal question.

Answer (score 4):

There's no implicit facility, but you can assign the comparison value to a variable:

```
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"], result;
if (result = (a.indexOf("orange") !== -1)){
  console.log(result);
}
```

*edit* — the same technique can be applied if you just want *part* of the evaluated expression:

```
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"], result;
if ((result = a.indexOf("orange")) !== -1){
  console.log(result);
}
```

Now the `.indexOf()` return value is retained in `result` instead of the comparison result.

Comment: i think you (as did i initially) slightly misread the question

Comment: Nice answer, Pointy

Comment: Thank you for this nifty way to dealing with the variable assignment

Comment: This will log `true`, not `2`.

Comment: @Barmar right; was it supposed to log 2? I don't know why that would make any sense, considering the topic. *edit* Oh oh I see, sorry. Minor change.

Answer (score 2):

If you want really terse code, you can assign a variable within the condition.

```js
var orangeIndex;
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"];
if ((orangeIndex = a.indexOf("orange")) !== -1) {
  console.log(orangeIndex);
}
```

You can also do it in a ternary:

```js
var orangeIndex;
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"]
var b = (((orangeIndex = a.indexOf("orange")) !== -1) ? orangeIndex : '');
console.log(b);
```

In both cases, don't forget the parentheses around the assignment. This is needed because assignment has lower precedence than comparison operators, so it would otherwise set the variable to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I refactor your code. You can hold result of condition in a variable.

```
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"];

var isOrange = a.indexOf("orange") !== -1;

if(isOrange){
  console.log(this) //as a.indexOf("orange") has been evaluated already above this prints 2
}

var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"]
var b = isOrange ? this : '') //"this" equals 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is in fact very simple. Example

```
if (yourvariable = yourcondition) {
    //Do something
} else if (yourvariable2 = yourcondition2) {
    //Do something else
} else if ((yourvariable3 = yourcondition3) || true) { //This is an else, but you memorized a condition inside it
    //Do something
}
```

When you assign a value to a variable, then the variable will hold that value and also, the result of the operator will be the value, therefore

```
if (foo = bar) {
    //Some operations
}
```

is equivalent logically to

```
if (bar) {
    foo = bar;
    //Some operations
}
```

but it is longer and if `bar` happens to be a `function` with a lot of operations, then it is not ideal to evaluate it twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as it gets

```
var a = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"], result;
if ((result = a.indexOf("orange")) !== -1) {
  console.log(result);
}
```

Here, @result = the index rather than the result of the logical operation that Pointy offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this through memoization. lodash provides a method to do this called `memoize`.

> Creates a function that memoizes the result of func. If resolver is provided, it determines the cache key for storing the result based on the arguments provided to the memoized function. By default, the first argument provided to the memoized function is used as the map cache key. The func is invoked with the this binding of the memoized function.

```
// your collection
const fruit = ["pear", "kiwi", "orange", "apple"]

/*
 * a basic indexOf function that we can memoize.
 * @example
 * indexOf(fruit)('kiwi') // 1
 */
const indexOf = list => Array.prototype.indexOf.bind(list)

/*
 * a memoized version of IndexOf that is seeded with the list
 * @example
 * memoizedIndexOfA('kiwi') // 1
 */
const memoizedIndexOfA = _.memoize(indexOf(fruit))

// the first time it is called in the `if` it is calculated
if (memoizedIndexOfA("orange") !== -1){

    // the value was previously calculated, so retrieve from the cache.
    console.log(memoizedIndexOfA("orange"))
}
```